# Update slack view generated on a view_submission event

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-dialog

I have a slack app which renders a form broken into multiple pages. For each modal form submission , I receive a view_submission event. I revert with a new view Object to this callback api.

Reference : https://slack.dev/java-slack-sdk/guides/modals

Now, on the last page modal view . I want to show a screen which shows multiple analytical details which can't be calculated within 3 seconds of allowed limit. So , I want to render a partial view and then update it asynchronously with some mechanism . Please help.

Things I have tried already .

1. Respond with a view object with a view_id (slack wouldn't allow this)

Comment: I was able to resolve this after contacting the slack support team.
So , apart from view_id , I can set external_id also in the view. 

I can store the external_id and then do a view.update using the external_id. 
It works fine